# jQuery - unrecognized expression: :nth-child

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select `:nth-child` using jquery, but it show syntax error.

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child
```

**Here is my code**

```
var i;
jQuery('#' + id + ' .tab-pane').each(function (id, t) {
    var n = jQuery(this).attr('id', 'pane-' + t);
    var p_id = n.attr('id');
    jQuery('#' + id + ' .nav-tabs li:nth-child(' + i + ') a').attr('href', p_id);
    i++;
});
```

please check my code what is missing here

Comment: No value assigned to `i`

Comment: Your javascript is valid, it must be failing somewhere else -> http://jsfiddle.net/72ELs/

Comment: Maybe you only posted the relevant code, but where is `i` assigned? You add 1 after an iteration, but I don't see any point where it's set to 0.

Comment: @user1671639 `i` is increment

Comment: @user007 `i` is not defined, and therefore stringifies to `undefined`. `:nth-child(undefined)` is not a valid selector.

Comment: @Sam Your code only works because nothing is selected. (In particular, the `.each` callback never runs, because there are no selected elements for it to operate over.) Here's your exact same code with HTML elements to select, which *does* reproduce the error: http://jsfiddle.net/72ELs/2/

Comment: @user007 `undefined` variable can't be incremented, it should have maybe `var i=0;`

Comment: @apsillers Good spot, I was expecting a full test case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the first iteration, there is no value for `i`. So the query looks like this:

```
jQuery('#' + id + ' .nav-tabs li:nth-child(undefined) a').attr('href', p_id);
```

On following iterations, it will be `undefined++`, which is `NaN`, which still won't work.

This obviously won't work. The solution is to set `i` to `1` (or to whatever value is necesary) on the first loop:

```
var i = 1;
```

Comment: Also, worth pointing out that if you put a space between `li:` and `nth-child` the same error will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('#'+id+' .tab-pane').each(function(id,t){
    var n = jQuery(this).attr('id','pane-'+t);
    var p_id = n.attr('id');
    jQuery('#'+ p_id).find('.nav-tabs li')
                   .eq(id)
                   .find('a')
                   .attr('href', p_id );
}
```

You can get rid of `i` as the `id` is an increment. And I'm guessing the second selector should use `p_id` rather than `id`.

Answer (score 1):

variable `i` is not assigned  **`undefined`**

```
var i;  //undefined
    jQuery('#'+id+' .tab-pane').each(function(id,t){
    var n = jQuery(this).attr('id','pane-'+t);
    var p_id = n.attr('id');
    jQuery('#'+id+' .nav-tabs li:nth-child('+i+') a').attr('href', p_id );
    i++; //still undefined
});
```